# Migrator fails with MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unknown data type: 'datetime2'

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-migrations, aspnetboilerplate

I am building a project from startup template **.Net Core v3.x** and Angular. The project works fine with MSSQL server. I am trying to use **MySql v8.0.27** instead, but when I run the Migrator I get the following error:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unknown data type: 'datetime2'
```

I am using the following packages

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.21
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 3.1.21
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 3.1.21
- Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 3.2.7
- MySqlConnector 0.69.10

My DBContextConfigurer class is

```cs
    {
        public static void Configure(DbContextOptionsBuilder<LandAndBnbDbContext> builder, string connectionString)
        {
            builder.UseMySql(connectionString);
        }

        public static void Configure(DbContextOptionsBuilder<LandAndBnbDbContext> builder, DbConnection connection)
        {
            builder.UseMySql(connection);
        }
    }
```

and my appsettings.json file is

```json
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "Server=localhost; port=3307; Database=xxx; user=xxx; password=xxx"
  }
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: `datetime2` is not a valid data type in `MySQL`.  Check for more info:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-types.html

Comment: That is correct... I am trying to find a way to overcome this

Answer (score 3):

Finally I managed to understand what is going and how to fix it...

For every database provider I should create a different set of Migrations, specific to every provider...

Solution from
https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/865#issuecomment-780138527